# Animate multiple steps

Tags: jquery

```
function moveto(step1, step2, step3) {
    var w = $(document).width();
    var h = $(document).height();
    $('#full').animate({
        left: -(step1 * w)}, {
        duration: 1000,
    });
    $('#full').animate({
        top: -(step2 * h)
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
    });       
}
```

I need this function to animate once then do another animate with different step.

Comment: I have an animations but i need to add multiple steps to it for example i need it to go left then down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to chain the animations using the [complete callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) :

```
function move(step1, step2, step3) {
    $('#full').animate({
        left: '+=' + step1,
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            top: '+=' + step2,
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-=' + step3
            }, 1000);
        });
    });   
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RHCqQ/

Comment: It is supposed to work ;)... What does it do? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Soory for late response, no it only runs the first animate and dosn't start the second

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#full').animate({left: -(step1 * w)}, {duration: 1000,}, function () {
        $('#full').animate({ top: -(step2 * h) }, {duration: 1000,});

} );
```

U can also pass the callback Function to animate function, once the animate is over your callback function will be executed. in callback function u can call other animate with different step.

you take an array and call the steps one by one using callback function.

Comment: It still only run's first animate only :(